# Any good quality neuro and reese bass tutorials [massive, FM8, Serum]

Tags: sound-design, music, synthesis, electronic-music, tutorial

Do you have any links of **quality** for neuro and reese bass sounds tutorials.

here is an example of neuro sound:

here is a reese bass example:

Thanks,

Comment: if you use the full link rather than the youth.be abbreviation, they will auto inline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend using square and saw waves detuned with some unison. I recommend you start with massive but serum is better if you have it. Modulate the wavetables in bend+/- or bend plus or bend - if you don't know what this is, read the manual or google it. This will add movement I recommend to synch this modulation. Add an extra oscillator to taste for character, experiment with volume and modulation till you like the sound. Add a very small amount of vibrato for randomness in the pitch (this helps when filtering and distorting the sound). Use a lowpass and a band pass in series but have both filters in the mix.

Experiment with this to find the right frequencies to sweep through with your modulation source. Use distortion to taste and map to the filters (again google if unsure of the massive routing tab) add chorus. Use camel phatt to distort the sound and eq to correct the frequency balance do not be afraid to go a little nuts (good speakers and room are required to learn this). Once you have a phatt modulating sound, load into kontakt and use the wave editor to play the nice bits and loop. Learn about mid side processing...

This is not all and steps are definitely missing it is just what I know so far.

Answer (score 0):

I also think you can check out the ["How to Bass" series by SeamlessR](https://www.youtube.com/user/SeamlessR/search?query=how+to+bass) on YouTube's channel

You may also check out [Frequent's tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=frequent+bass+tutorial+) on YouTube.

Cheers and all the best

Comment: Thx!!! I knew seamless but not Frequent